# How to pass user defined parameters to rpmbuild to fill variables

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

is it possible to pass parameters to rpmbuild to fill user defined variables that are called inside the spec file?

Example: 
The user defined variable %{foobar} which is called in the .spec file (but empty) should be filled with the variable which is passed when executing the rpmbuild command

```
rpmbuild -bb --foobar="Foo" somespecfile.spec
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
rpmbuild -bb --define '_foobar Foo' somespecfile.spec
```

and refer it within the spec as %{_foobar}

(the _ is a convention, not a must)

Answer (score 5):

The closest you can get AFAIK are conditional builds, which allow you to do things like

```
rpmbuild -ba newpackage.spec --with feature
```

see http://rpm.org/user_doc/conditional_builds.html .

Comment: thank you - this sounds like an option. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

could add this into the SPEC file:

```
%define _topdir %(echo $PWD)/
```