# How to pass variables into spec files?

Tags: fedora, redhat, rpm, specifications

I am writing my first spec file and one thing I do not understand is how to make it dynamic. 
I am using other spec files as reference and noticed that many have name / version loaded dynamically. I am wondering how to do this? Here is an example:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/branches/0.94/src/packages/rpm/spec/hbase.spec

Mainly I am wondering what these sections mean:

```
%define _source      @package.name@
%define _final_name  @final.name@ 
%define _prefix      @package.prefix@
%define _bin_dir     %{_prefix}/bin 
%define _conf_dir    @package.conf.dir@
%define _include_dir %{_prefix}/include
....
```

Also I'm wondering what exactly {_prefix} actually is?

Sorry for the newbie questions. I'm having an unusual amount of trouble finding info on this.

Answer (score 0):

`%{_prefix}` (and lots of other macros) are defined in `/usr/lib/rpm/macros`. These are read by `rpmbuild` and substituted when parsing the spec file. `%{_prefix}` specifically denotes the installation prefix which is used when installing things into the root filesystem. This usually is `/usr`. Macros in `/usr/lib/rpm/macros*` define paths and more according to the file system layout and packaging conventions of the distribution one is building the package on. For instance, a distro might for some reason want to have all binaries installed in `/foo/bin`, in which case it would ship an macro file with the `%{_bindir}` macro set accordingly.

All keys between `@` (such as `@package.name@`) **usually** denote placeholders for autoconf variables, these are substituted when running `autoconf`, see [1]. These are often used to automatically generate an appropriate file (in this case, spec file) from a template (which includes the said `@` delimited placeholders) when configuring a source package.

As far as passing other variables is concerned, here are some options [2]. These may be used when the user wishes to be able to dynamically control certain aspects of the package.

[1] http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html

[2] [How to pass user defined parameters to rpmbuild to fill variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559477/how-to-pass-user-defined-parameters-to-rpmbuild-to-fill-variables/)